# "Clone" method and "Cloneable" Interface with different scenarios,

Tags: java, clone

What are possible run time exceptions that can occur,when we try to make a clone of a class in java except CloneNotSupportedException?

Comment: Technically, any instance of `Throwable` can be thrown if the author of a class decides to `throw` it in his implementation of `clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding a deep copy clone() method and you try to dereference a null value at runtime is the only one I can think of.

CloneNotSupported is a compile time exception that you'll get if you implement Cloneable but don't override Object's clone() method.